Wigner's Friend distance in MWI
In Wigner's Friend let's say that upon observing the dead cat, he would move 5 meters forward, while if he sees a live cat, he would move 5 meters backwards.
In MWI, there is no collapse and we have superposition of:

Dead cat, Wigner's Friend (Friend A) is 5 meters forward
Live cat, Wigner's Friend (Friend B) is 5 meters backwards

I know it is said that because of decoherence these 2 do not interact and are "in their own worlds".
But is the distance between Friend A and Friend B 10 meters? Is the distance 70 billion light years or more (e.g. beyond their respective observable universes)?
This is related to the idea of "splitting worlds" in MWI. I saw this question - Where are the worlds in many-worlds interpretation?. In it, the top answer says that:

So for $n$ particles there is a $3n$ dimensional configuration space. And the quantum wavefunction is a function from $\mathbb R^{3n}$ into the complex numbers (or into a joint spin state if you have spin).

This part I understand. The next part I kind of understand, but I still have some questions:

So it is much like a series of space ships in a thousand dimensional space and making little detours when a location in the large space means two particles are close Eventually the two branches have wiggled into slightly different places in the configuration space to the point where it would be hopeless to have them ever cross each again. Either on purpose or on accident.

So my questions are:

Is the distance between Friend A and Friend B in space (or spacetime) - is it 10 meters?
If they are in different places in this $\mathbb R^{3n}$ configuration space, can a meaningful distance function between them be constructed? Would that distance be measured in meters or in some other unit?
Can any 2 points in the $\mathbb R^{3n}$ configuration space have the distance between them calculated?


It's just not meaningful to talk about distances if they are between points in different universes.

Why is it not meaningful? If it's a space (even a configuration space), shouldn't it have coordinates and thus distances? For example, a distance function in this space could be defined mathematically, as the Euclidean distance between two points in the $\mathbb R^{3n}$ configuration space.

The friends do not exist in configuration space. Each single point in configuration space represents a possible configuration of the entire universe. A distance between two points in configuration space would be some sort of representation of the magnitude of the difference between the corresponding two possible universes.

In quantum theory in general the expectation value of an observable at the end of an experiment depends on what happens to all of the possible values of an observable during the experiment: this is called interference. For an example see Section 2 of this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
If information is copied out of a system this suppresses interference: an effect called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
For systems you see in everyday life, information is copied out of them on a timescale much shorter than the timescale over which they change significantly so interference is very heavily suppressed. As a result, there are multiple versions of those systems with different values of the monitored observables that evolve autonomously and they form layers each of which evolves approximately like the universe as described by classical physics, hence the name of the MWI:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
Now if you're talking about two different objects like me and my desk there is a measurable quantity that describes the distance between me and my desk and it may say we are ten metres apart or something like that. If you're talking about two different versions of my desk then the distance between those different versions isn't measurable.
I could say that I will measure a radioactive atom after one half life and if it has decayed then I will move it 5m forward and otherwise I will move it 5m backward. I could then work out the set of possible values of the desk's position and you could then work out the standard deviation and similar quantities and one such measure might say the spread of different versions of the desk is 10m. Since expectation values are experimentally testable
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048
the accuracy of that measure could be tested. The situation is more complicated and less straightforward than saying the different versions are ten metres apart.
